# How to convert SecByteBlock to string?

Tags: c++, security, aes, crypto++

I'm having a problem trying to convert `SecByteBlock` to string.
Here's my case:

I want to encrypt user access data using AES with static key and dynamic iv.
My code is something like this:

```
AesKeyIvFactory aesKeyIvFactory;
SecByteBlock key = aesKeyIvFactory.loadKey();
SecByteBlock iv = aesKeyIvFactory.createIv();

encryptionService->encode(&userAccess, key, iv);
std::string token = std::string(iv.begin(), iv.end()) + userAccess;
```

The code above is supposed to:

1. Load key from file;
2. Create iv;
3. Encrypt (AES) user access data;
4. Concatenate the iv with the user data access encrypted to create a "token";

Running a test several times, sometimes (1 to 10 times) the `std::string(iv.begin(), iv.end())` doesn't work correctly. It seems like there is a "line break" in the iv that makes the conversion fail.

I tried a lot of things, but nothing works and I don't have experience with c++.

I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: How do you know it isn't working? (It's more likely that printing the string does the wrong thing than constructing it.)

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate), see [string to SecByteBlock conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26145776).

Comment: Now available on the Crypto++ wiki: [`SecBlock`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/SecBlock). The wiki page includes conversion examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Eric answered your primary question on how to convert the `SecByteBlock` to a `std::string` (including the explicit conversions between `char*` and `byte*`). But here's how you might approach `std::string token = std::string(iv.begin(), iv.end()) + userAccess;` issue.

```c++
string token;

SecByteBlock iv(16), userAccess(16);
OS_GenerateRandomBlock(false, iv, iv.size());
OS_GenerateRandomBlock(false, userAccess, userAccess.size());

SecByteBlock nil;
nil.CleanNew(HMAC<SHA256>::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);

HMAC<SHA256> hmac;
hmac.SetKey(nil.data(), nil.size());

HashFilter filter(hmac, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(token)));
filter.Put(iv.data(), iv.size());
filter.Put(userAccess.data(), userAccess.size());
filter.MessageEnd();

cout << token << endl;
```

The `SecByteBlock nil` creates an object with no memory or size. The `nil.CleanNew(HMAC<SHA256>::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH)` sizes and initializes the `SecByteBlock` to 0. Otherwise, you have an uninitialized block of memory.

It is possible to declare it and size it with a 0-inialized array, but you have to be familiar with the sources because its no Doxygen-docimented as of Crypto++ 5.6.2. That way is to use a `NULL` pointer, but a non-0 size. Here's what it would look like, but its very non-intuitive:

```
SecByteBlock nil(NULL, HMAC<SHA256>::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
```

The trick relies on this [`SecBlock<T>`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/secblock_8h_source.html) constructor:

```
00250    SecBlock(const T *t, size_type len)
00251        : m_size(len)
00252    {
00253        m_ptr = m_alloc.allocate(len, NULL);
00254        if (t == NULL)
00255            memset_z(m_ptr, 0, len*sizeof(T));
00256        else
00257            memcpy(m_ptr, t, len*sizeof(T));
00258    }
```

---

If possible, you should use `HKDF` instead of the `HMAC<SHA>` with a `nil` vector to extract the entropy from the security parameters. You can find the `HKDF` in the repo at the [`HKDF class`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/hkdf.h). Its a stand alone header, so it will "just work".

---

A typical run of the program with random values for `iv` and `userAccess` is:

```
$ ./cryptopp-test.exe
061CF705259058C4E01A2BF22830FC3F2A7E97F12FE605B38405B1E1B19A9E0F
```

---

Another way to approach it could be concatenation based on `SecByteBlock`'s `operator +=`. The result is a binary string, and not a human readable ASCII string.

```c++
SecByteBlock result;

result += iv;
result += SecByteBlock(userAccess.data(), userAccess.size());

string token(result.data(), result.size());
```

If you need a human readable string, then run it through a `HexEncoder`:

```
HexEncoder hex(new StringSink(token));
hex.Put(result.data(), result.size());
hex.MessageEnd();
```

But it does not extract the entropy from the parameters, so I personally like it less.

---

When you move from a `SecByteBlock` to a `std::string`, you effectively lose your secure allocator. That means the data in the copies will not be zeroized after egressing data to the `string` object.

---

The [`HexEncoder`](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HexEncoder) is a convenience item, and it allows you to dump the binary string.

Another useful one might be the [`Base64URLEncoder`](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Base64URLEncoder). It uses the web safe alphabet.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm having a problem trying to convert SecByteBlock to string

If the issue is with conversion from `SecByteBlock` and its `byte` array to a `std::string` and its `char` array, then you should:

```
SecByteBlock iv;
...

// C-style cast
std::string token = std::string((const char*)iv.data(), iv.size()) + userAccess;
```

Or,

```
SecByteBlock iv;
...

// C++-style cast
std::string token = std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(iv.data()), iv.size()) + userAccess;
```

You can also forgo the assignment, and just initialize and later append:

```
SecByteBlock iv;
...

std::string token(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(iv.data()), iv.size());
...

std::string userAccess;
...

token += userAccess;
```

---

The other problem you might have is `string` to `SecByteBlock`. You should do this:

```
std::string str;
...

// C-style cast
SecByteBlock sbb((const byte*)str.data(), str.size());
```

Or:

```
std::string str;
...

// C++-style cast
SecByteBlock sbb(reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(str.data()), str.size());
```

Comment: I've already tried this, but this line breaks with the message: "Error: no instance of constructor..."

I've tried too:

`std::string token = std::string((char *)iv.data(), iv.size()) + userAccess;`

But the test still breaks sometimes.

Comment: I have the same problem, and when I try this, i get : *error: invalid conversion from ‘CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char>::pointer {aka unsigned char*}’ to ‘const char*’ *