# SecByteBlock to string conversion errors

Tags: c++, crypto++, libcrafter

I have to send a randomly generated number (`rng`) within a packet, and, thus, have to convert a `SecByteBlock`. I use [`libcrafter`](https://github.com/pellegre/libcrafter) to put `rng` array into a `RawLayer` packet.

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31930838/3494633); but it gets me an *invalid conversion* error.

Here's the code I use:

```
AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
SecByteBlock rng1;
prng.GenerateBlock( rng1, rng1.size() );

string rng1_str(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(rng1));

std::string rng1_str = std::string(rng1.data(), rng1.size());

Crafter::RawLayer number(rng1_str);
```

The two ideas don't work, both give me:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char>::pointer {aka unsigned char*}’
to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
std::string rng1_str = std::string(rng1.data(), rng1.size());
```

Since the `RawLayer` accepts as constructor a `std::string` or a `const byte*`, I'd like to convert the `SecBlockByte` into one of these two formats...

Comment: Try to read the error message again, it tells you what you pass to the `std::string` constructor, and what the constructor expects. The difference between them is very small and could reasonably be solved with a simple `reinterpret_cast`. However, the bigger problem is how you will *use* the string object. Will you try to use it as text? Then you might have problems as the data is most likely *not* textual.

Comment: I think it wants a `unsigned char *`, but I tried to reinterpret the cast with that, and it didn't work either...

Comment: The error message says that you try to pass `unsigned char *`, when the constructor wants `const char *`. Try casting to `char*`.

Comment: Didn't work either. I also tried to cast to `unsigned char`...

Comment: You sure? Casting to `char*` [should work fine](http://ideone.com/V3uej5).

Comment: I know, but I got this : `error: invalid cast from type ‘CryptoPP::SecByteBlock {aka CryptoPP::SecBlock<unsigned char>}’ to type ‘char*’ `. I think it's the `SecByteBlock`, which isn't really a unsigned char*...

Comment: Now you are doing something *different*. The error message in the question specifically says `unsigned char *`, i.e. a *pointer*.

Comment: @Eisen - Since you cited the other question and answers, I improved Eric's answer to explicitly call out the conversions for future visitors. You found it, so others will like find it, too.

Comment: Now available on the Crypto++ wiki: [`SecBlock`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/SecBlock). The wiki page includes conversion examples.

Answer (score 1):

The output of the PRNG likely has an embedded NULL, so you can't operate on its data with customary C-string operations. That means the first statement is probably wrong.

> ```
> string rng1_str(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(rng1));
>
> std::string rng1_str = std::string(rng1.data(), rng1.size());
> ```

I'm not sure what you are doing with the second statement, but it needs to be cast just like the first one (and you can do away with the assignment):

```
std::string rng1_str(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(rng1.data()), rng1.size());
```

---

Since you said you *"the `RawLayer` accepts as constructor a `std::string` or a `const byte*`"*, you might try:

```
SecByteBlock rng(16);
prng.GenerateBlock( rng, rng.size() );

Crafter::RawLayer number( rng.data(), rng.size() );
```

Also, be sure to size the `SecByteBlock`. A raw declaration of one is a 0-sized array with *no* memory block backing it. That is, `rng.size()` will be 0 with just the following:

```
SecByteBlock rng;
```

You can also do the following:

```
SecByteBlock rng;
// Make it 16-bytes in size, memory uninitialized
rng.New(16);
```

Or:

```
SecByteBlock rng;
// Make it 16-bytes in size, memory initialized to 0
rng.CleanNew(16);
```

If you want to get really fancy and avoid the runtime allocation of the memory block, then use a [`FixedSizeSecBlock`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/secblock_8h_source.html):

```
FixedSizeSecBlock<byte, 16> rng;
```

But this is a more advanced technique, so don't get bogged down with it.

---

I find C/C++ unwillingness to automatically convert between a `signed char` and an `unsigned char` very annoying because its all just 8-bit binary data to me (I understand the need for the language rules). But I think its ridiculous I need a `reinterpret_cast` rather than a `static_cast`.

Answer (score 0):

As the aim was to put the `SecByteBlock` into a `Crafter::RawLayer`, I simply had to cast it into a `const byte*`...

The following lines do the thing.

```
SecByteBlock rng1;
prng.GenerateBlock( rng1, rng1.size() );

Crafter::RawLayer number(reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(rng1.data()), rng1.size());
```