# How to cast a char* to a byte* in c++?

Tags: c++, string, encryption, byte, crypto++

I am very new in c++ and want to cast a `char*` from a `std::string` to a `byte*`.

Here is my code:

```
inline string XOR(const string &value, const string &key) {
  string retval(value);
  CryptoPP::xorbuf(&retval[0], &key[0], retval.length());
  return retval;
}
```

In `g++`, the output is:

```
AESXCBC128.cpp: In function ‘std::string CryptoPP::XOR(const string&, const string&)’:
AESXCBC128.cpp:79:48: error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘byte* {aka unsigned char*}’ [-fpermissive]
     xorbuf(&retval[0], &key[0], retval.length());
                                                ^
AESXCBC128.cpp:45:6: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void CryptoPP::xorbuf(byte*, const byte*, size_t)’ [-fpermissive]
 void xorbuf(byte *buf, const byte *mask, size_t count)
      ^
AESXCBC128.cpp:79:48: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘const byte* {aka const unsigned char*}’ [-fpermissive]
     xorbuf(&retval[0], &key[0], retval.length());
                                                ^
AESXCBC128.cpp:45:6: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘void CryptoPP::xorbuf(byte*, const byte*, size_t)’ [-fpermissive]
 void xorbuf(byte *buf, const byte *mask, size_t count)
```

Comment: a char is not a string in c++

Comment: It seems like you are using nonstandard C++, or you copied a Java code. C++ doesn't have type `byte`, `word32`, or `word64`.

Comment: @DannyuNDos - I bet they are just typedefs, which is part of the standard. The real problem here is that `byte` is `unsigned char` and the strings contain `char`, a different type. The compiler also says that adding an `-fpermissive` option will make it ignore the error. Could be a temporary solution.

Comment: Now available on the Crypto++ wiki: [`SecBlock`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/SecBlock). The wiki page includes conversion examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> inline string XOR(const string &value, const string &key) {
>   string retval(value);
>   CryptoPP::xorbuf(&retval[0], &key[0], retval.length());
>   return retval;
> }
> ```

Crypto++ [typedefs a `byte` in `confg.h`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/config.h#L226):

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
```

You can use something like:

```
CryptoPP::xorbuf(
    reinterpret_cast<byte*>(&retval[0]),
    reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(&key[0]),
    retval.length());
```

Or, you can do it with C-style casts:

```
CryptoPP::xorbuf((byte*)&retval[0], (const byte*)&key[0], retval.length());
```

---

Here are some similar questions for `SecByteBlock`, which is a byte array rather than a char array:

- [How to convert SecByteBlock to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31929531/608639)
- [string to SecByteBlock conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26145776/608639)

Here are some references on C++ casting:

- [When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332030/608639)
- [Regular cast vs. static_cast vs. dynamic_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28002/608639)

Comment: @T.Rifle - Maybe you should checkout [some search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+for+beginners) to help with future questions. Stack Overflow is not the easiest forum for those new to a language. Its kind of a well known problem with Stack Overflow. Also see [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users).